# how can do a special join left on ODI between two tables

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-data-integrator

I would like to join between two tables (A and B)  and I wanna insert rows which are not in table B and are not on the intersection (like I show you on picture), insert them into table B.

if I am on sql I can do like :

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.key = B.key
WHERE B.key IS NULL
```

but on ODI. I can't do it. I just coched the Left Outer Join but it didn't fix my issue , by Left Outer Join I can take all rows which are on table A and rows which are on the intersection between A and B.

What I need is just extract all rows which are on table A without the rows which are on the intersection. how can I fix this on  ODI

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: so you mean if table A has 1,2,3 and table B has 2,3,4 then you need only 1?

Comment: Gave the answer below. Check and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

1. You can create a inner join for A.key = B.key in ODI interface
2. Edit this inner join and replace the join condition with A.key (+) = B.key
3. Save the interface
4. Create a filter in the interface with `WHERE B.key IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1,col2.... from A 
minus 
select col1,col2.... from B
```

OR if A and B has different structure, then

```
 select * from A 
 where A.key not in (select distinct(key) from B)
```

Comment: I don't want it in SQL I want to use in Oracle Data Integrator, you understand

Comment: You can do the same thing using two datasets with a Minus operator between them in ODI 11g. Or use a SET component if you are using ODI 12c.

Comment: @JeromeFr I am using ODI 12c OH yes I have seen this Set Component, I will use it thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ODI 11g, you can do the join in a yellow (temporary) interface, they reuse that interface in a blue interface where you can apply the filter. Make sure you select "Use as Derived Statement (Sub-Select)" on the source in the blue interface. By doing that, the yellow interface will be a subquery and you are sure the filter is applied after the join.

If you are using ODI 12c, you can do the join in a dataset component and add a filter on the output of the dataset. So you are sure the filter is applied after the join.

Comment: where we can use a Set component ?

Comment: What we can do with Dataset

Comment: The Dataset and Set components are both available in the ["Component" pane](http://www.rittmanmead.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/components_ds.png).

[This blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/entry/user_interface_and_terminology_changes2) from the ODI team at Oracle explains how to use Set and Dataset components

Comment: thanks for your answer, please do you know how can I create a temporary table for a Mapping just to use it temporarily

Comment: This is not possible in ODI 12c. You need to create the table on the database level and reverse-engineer it, or create a datastore manually and have a step in your KM that create the target table.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make ODI generate the SQL you provide without the need to resort to set based operations (MINUS), which should also perform better.

Can you make sure you split the logic in mapping and put `A.key = B.key` condition in the JOIN and a *separate* FILTER `B.key IS NULL`?